# How to send a POST XHR request with FormData in the same format than when using a Submit button?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I have a `<form>` that I normally send with a `submit` button:

```
<form action='/doit' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='ex1_q1' value='AAA'>
<input type='text' name='ex2_q1' value='BVB'>
<input type='submit' value='Go'>
</form>
```

This is working.

Every 10 seconds, I also want to (silently, in the background) send this `<form>` content with AJAX. However I noticed that when doing this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
    fd.append("dt", +new Date);    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/doit");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(fd); 
}, 10 * 1000);
```

the data is sent indeed, but the server **does not receive it the same format** that when sending with the "Submit button".

More precisely:

1. when sent with Ajax/XHR, the body is something like:

   ```
   b'------WebKitFormBoundaryQb7yIKHLZODhAjqI\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ex1_q1"\r\n\r\nAAA\r\n------WebK
   ```
2. when sent with the Submit button, I get:

   ```
   b'ex1_q1=AAA&ex2_q1=BVB&accept=on&numero=1'
   ```

   which is what I want in all cases

**Question: with an XHR request, how to have the data sent with the same format than with a Submit button (case 2.)?**

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for pointing this, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `enctype` attribute, form data is submitted as either "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data".

A FormData object will always encode data as "multipart/form-data".

If you want "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" then you should use a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For completeness, can you include how to `xhr.send(...)` an existing `<form>` from the DOM with this URLSearchParams function?

Comment: PS: here is what I want to achieve: send the form every 10 seconds silently in background (without redirecting to the success page like when really clicking on "Submit" button).

Comment: PS : it's not super obvious how to turn an existing <form> with a few <input>s into something that can be sent with `xhr.send(...)`, could you add this? Thank you in advance @Quentin!